# Hovering over icons that changes colour

Tags: javascript, html

So I am playing around with something with JavaScript. I am trying to get my `div` to change colour once the user has hovered over it, then once the user leaves it should return to the original colour . Here is my code. For some reason my browser (chrome) isn't displaying it even though everything seems right, but maybe someone can spot something that I cant

```js
var bookEventsInfo = document.getElementById("bookEventsInfo");

bookEventsInfo.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
  sources.syle.color = "green";
})
bookEventsInfo.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(){
   bookEventsInfo.syle.color = "grey";
})
```

```html
<div id="bookEventsInfo">
  <i class="fas fa-book-open fa-5x"></i>
  <hr>
  <p>Book Events allows the user<br>to select and manage bookings<br>of certain events to choose from</p>


  <!-- <p>Book Events form will allow you to<br>Select specifc events from a list<br>and can make bookings</p> -->
</div>
```

Comment: is your javascript snippet correct? you've got two different variable names `sources` and `bookEventsInfo`

Answer (score 1):

You can use straight CSS for this. In your styles add something like the following:

```
.element:hover {
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in `syle` should be `style`. The event should be `mouseenter`.

> The `mouseenter` event is ***only*** triggered when the mouse pointer enters the div element. The `onmousemove` event triggers ***every time*** the mouse pointer is moved over the div element.

There is no `source` defined in your code. Also you can use `this` object to refer the current element:

```js
var bookEventsInfo = document.getElementById("bookEventsInfo");

bookEventsInfo.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
  this.style.color = "green";
})
bookEventsInfo.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(){
   this.style.color = "#000";
})
```

```html
<div id="bookEventsInfo">
  <i class="fas fa-book-open fa-5x"></i>
  <hr>
  <p>Book Events allows the user<br>to select and manage bookings<br>of certain events to choose from</p>


  <!-- <p>Book Events form will allow you to<br>Select specifc events from a list<br>and can make bookings</p> -->
</div>
```

Though the preferred way is using CSS:

```css
#bookEventsInfo:hover{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="bookEventsInfo">
  <i class="fas fa-book-open fa-5x"></i>
  <hr>
  <p>Book Events allows the user<br>to select and manage bookings<br>of certain events to choose from</p>


  <!-- <p>Book Events form will allow you to<br>Select specifc events from a list<br>and can make bookings</p> -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mamuns answer here is a jQuery implementation of the above.
Although CSS is the best way to achieve this as answered by others.

```js
/* jQuery implementation */
$("#bookEventsInfo").on("mouseover", function() {
  this.style.color = "green";
});

$("#bookEventsInfo").on("mouseout", function() {
  this.style.color = "";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="bookEventsInfo">
  <i class="fas fa-book-open fa-5x"></i>
  <hr>
  <p>
    Book Events allows the user<br>to select and manage bookings<br>of certain events to choose from
  </p>
</div>
```